# Custom (editable) message for each user after login

Tags: unity, login, customization, notification, notification-area

The computer is being used by three users (+1 admin) and they use unity login. The three users come, use the computer and logout. I have to give some instructions, news and details every time they login.

I want to have a utility/tool where I can type in a custom message to each user.  The latest message would then be displayed on the desktop (for each user) (with date of my last edit) for say 10-15 secs. A copy of the text also be available (to the user) somewhere with all messages and dates like a log.

[image]

*Admin has SSH access to the system.

I am not sure if this is possible (and may be I am looking for too much !).

Comment: Can be done. What's your targeted version of Ubuntu ? Are popups ok ? Or you'd prefer on-screen text like your example shows ?

Comment: Running 14.04 LTS and no plans to upgrade anytime soon.   Popups / notification are fine if they stay for some seconds (~10-15 sec)

Comment: I've implemented a quick script, posted an answer. It allows creating a file and that file will be matched to each user.  Let me know what other functionality you'd want me to add there,and in case you need any other clarification. The script is not fancy , but fairly stable.

Comment: Hi @ankit7540 posted my answer, in the first "edition", forgot to mention to make the script executable, but that might be obvious :)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @Serg  : I like the approach, let me test and reply.

Comment: @Jacob Vlijm  : it looks great.  I will check it on a separate system. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: It is becoming difficult for me to accept an answer ! Both are excellent answers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do that in the following setup, which will produce a semi- transparent window, staying for an arbitrary time:

1. Create in a (any) directory, in which each of the users *at least* has *read* permissions, for each user a message file, *exactly* named after each user's username (log in name), no extension, e.g.

   ```
   jacob
   ```

   Add text to the file as your message. If you add a *new* message, start with `###`, the script will then automatically display the last message. The text can contain anything you like, it will look exactly like you put it in the file.

   - The *latest* message, will be copied as `latest_message.txt` to the user's home directory for reference.
   - As it is, the window will stay for 15 seconds, but you can set it to any value, even make it automatically depend on the length of the text.

   An example file could look like:

   ```
   Vraag:
   Een aap op een fiets, hoe vind je zoiets?

   Opdracht:
   Geef antwoord op de vraag!

   ###
   Vraag:
   Hoe is de koffie vandaag?

   Opdracht:
   Zet het zelf even als het niet te drinken is!
   ```

   The message then would look like:

   [image]
2. Copy the script below into an empty file, edit in the head section of your script the path to the folder in which you store the user(s) messages. Save the script as `show_personalmessage` in (e.g.) `/usr/local/bin` (which should be in `$PATH` **and make it executable(!)** (no extension)

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import subprocess
   import os
   import gi
   gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
   from gi.repository import GObject, Gtk, Gdk, Pango
   from threading import Thread
   import time
   import getpass

   # --- set the path to the message files below, filename = username
   filedir = "/home/jacob/Bureaublad"
   # --- set the time to show the window below
   showtime = 15
   # ---

   # don't change anything below
   user = getpass.getuser()
   currmessage = os.environ["HOME"]+"/latest_message.txt"
   f = filedir+"/"+user
   text = "Welcome "+user+"\n\n"+open(f).read().split("###")[-1]
   open(currmessage, "wt").write(text)

   class Splash(Gtk.Window):

       def __init__(self):
           Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="splashtitle")
           maingrid = Gtk.Grid()
           self.add(maingrid)
           maingrid.set_border_width(80)
           # set text for the spash window
           label = Gtk.Label(text)
           label.modify_font(Pango.FontDescription('Ubuntu 12'))
           maingrid.attach(label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
           self.stop = Thread(target=self.close_window)
           self.stop.start()

       def close_window(self):
           time.sleep(showtime)
           Gtk.main_quit()

   def splashwindow():
       window = Splash()
       window.set_decorated(False)
       window.set_resizable(False)
       window.override_background_color(Gtk.StateType.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(0,0,0,1))
       window.modify_fg(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.color_parse("grey"))
       window.set_opacity(0.8)
       window.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
       window.show_all()
       GObject.threads_init()
       Gtk.main()

   splashwindow()
   ```
3. Create a launcher in `/etc/xdg/autostart`

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Type=Application
   Name=Splash 
   Exec=/bin/bash -c "sleep 10 && show_personalmessage"
   ```

   The sleep 10 is to make sure the desktop is "ready" to open the window.

#### Explanation

- Launchers in `/etc/xdg/autostart` run commands *for each user* on log in.
- The launcher then runs the window (called by the command `show_personalmessage`), which looks for the personalized message in the directory you defined. Additionally. The most recent message is copied to the user's home directory.
- If required, the path to the message can be altered, even be made user specific by using the `getpass` -module, so that the script (window) will look for a user- specific named file in a directory. Please mention if that would be required.

#### Additionally

The (Gtk) window

- can be made to stay below everything, as if it would be part of the background
- can be made stay *on top* of everything
- can be made closeable

etc, etc...

---

### EDIT

To save time writing messages, as discussed [in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39778/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-ankit7540), below a version of the script in which you can include a few "permanent" sections:

- `premsg`, which should be just below "Welcome user x", and the body of your message, and
- `postmsg`, which comes as the bottom section of your message.

Both sections can be set to none, just by setting `""` as a value.

[image]

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import os
import gi
gi.require_version('Gtk', '3.0')
from gi.repository import GObject, Gtk, Gdk, Pango
from threading import Thread
import time
import getpass

# --- set the path to the message files below, filename = username
filedir = "/path/to/message_directory"
# --- set the time to show the window below
showtime = 15
# --- set pre-message below. set premessage = "" for no pre-message
premsg = """We assume you read all 3782 instruction pages on how to use
Ubuntu before you push any button on this computer.
""" 
# --- set post-message below. set postmessage = "" for no post-message
postmsg = """Before you go to sleep tonight, make sure to brush your
teeth for at least half an hour
"""

# --- don't change anything below
user = getpass.getuser()
currmessage = os.environ["HOME"]+"/latest_message.txt"
f = filedir+"/"+user

text = "Welcome "+user+"\n\n"+premsg+"\n"+open(f).read().split("###")[-1]+"\n"+postmsg

open(currmessage, "wt").write(text)

class Splash(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="splashtitle")
        maingrid = Gtk.Grid()
        self.add(maingrid)
        maingrid.set_border_width(80)
        # set text for the spash window
        label = Gtk.Label(text)
        label.modify_font(Pango.FontDescription('Ubuntu 12'))
        maingrid.attach(label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.stop = Thread(target=self.close_window)
        self.stop.start()

    def close_window(self):
        time.sleep(showtime)
        Gtk.main_quit()

def splashwindow():
    window = Splash()
    window.set_decorated(False)
    window.set_resizable(False)
    window.override_background_color(Gtk.StateType.NORMAL, Gdk.RGBA(0,0,0,1))
    window.modify_fg(Gtk.StateFlags.NORMAL, Gdk.color_parse("white"))
    window.set_opacity(0.8)
    window.set_position(Gtk.WindowPosition.CENTER)
    window.show_all()
    GObject.threads_init()
    Gtk.main()

splashwindow()
```

#### Note

Of course, just like the message *body*, yoy can alter the script to read the pre- and post messages from a file, which makes it even more convenient to maintain. Did it like this, for reasons of simplicity in the answer.

Comment: Tried. It works very nicely.  Looking at the code I understand how to change the time its stays.
One question: What if I do not have SSH access to the user's home (but only to my home)  ?

Comment: You (or I) can set any path, but we need to make it use `getpass` then to make each user atomatically request the named file. What path would you have in mind? It must be a path that each user has read access to. Wait, will edit in a minute...

Comment: @ankit7540 edited it into the script (and into the explanation).

Comment: @ankit7540 Ah, I see you first line: "Welcome user..." Is that important to you? is just a line in the code if it is.

Comment: About that line "Welcome $user", you can just tell me here  and I can add it in the script.  Additionally, consider user has a folder,   `/home/message`. It would be good to copy the recent message text (catenate etc.. ) in a  fixed file (for reference )

Comment: @ankit7540 both are edited in, while I was on it. If I understand well that is. Now the message starts with "Welcome...", and the latest message is copied to the user's home directory as `latest_message.txt`. It will be overwritten on the next log in with the new message.

Comment: @ankit7540 Could you run it from the terminal and post what is the message? What is exactly not working (any more)? You know you have to edit the `filedir = "/home/jacob/Bureaublad"` line do you :)

Comment: `./show_personalmessage
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./show_personalmessage", line 21, in <module>
    text = "Welcome "+user+"\n\n"+open(f).read().split("###")[-1]
NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory: '/home/server_admin/server_admin/server_admin'
`    From the above output  I corrected the path and it now works. Thanks  for the help here .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39778/discussion-between-jacob-vlijm-and-ankit7540).

Answer (score 6):

The script bellow allows admin to store personalized messages in form `username_mm_dd_yyyy.txt` in admin-defined directory. Usernames are determined automatically and matched against filename and date of the file to be displayed.

The script can also have a `.desktop` entry which is to be placed into `/etc/xdg/autostart` directory . That will make the script to be displayed for each user. Alternatively you can place the `.desktop` file into each individual user's `~/.config/autostart` directory.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
_get_username()
{
  qdbus  com.canonical.Unity  \
        /com/canonical/Unity/Session \
        com.canonical.Unity.Session.UserName
}

_get_date()
{
  date +%m_%d_%Y
}

_show_error()
{
  MESSAGE="Can't read the file or file doesn't exist. Contact the admin for assistance"

  zenity --error --title="Ooops, something went wrong!" --text="$MESSAGE"
}

main()
{
  # replace this with the actual directory 
  # that you want to use for storing messages
  MESSAGES_DIRECTORY="/tmp"

  # file name is made up of username_mm_dd_yyyy
  FILE="$MESSAGES_DIRECTORY"/"$( _get_username )"_"$( _get_date )".txt
  echo "$FILE"
  if [ -r "$FILE"   ] ; then
     zenity --text-info  --title="Welcome, $( _get_username )" --filename="$FILE"
  else
     _show_error
  fi
}

main
```

Bellow you can see a small demo of the script in action. I have created the file in specified format in my `/tmp` folder

[image]

Comment: Sorry to keep you waiting. It works super nice. I like the buttons  'Cancel'  and 'OK'. I used it with .desktop entry and it works perfect !

Comment: @ankit7540 Glad you like it. Any additional features that you'd want me to add ?

Comment: Consider user has a folder,   `/home/message`. It would be good to copy the recent message file and keep there for reference.

Comment: @ankit7540 can be done. It's merely a matter of adding a line with `cp` command , first argument is the admin's copy and second argument`/home/$( _get_username )/messages/$FILE.txt` I do need to sleep but i can add that in the morning. It's just one line.

Comment: And if you want to catenate the file thats just `cat $FILE >> /home/$( _get_username )/messages/Log_of_all_messages. txt`