# How can I display text from a file automatically after powering up my computer, in text editor or terminal?

Tags: bash, scripts

I would like to see my task list each time I power up my computer e.g from file in my Desktop. How I can do it? It can be shown on terminal or in open file what ever.

Comment: I have answered something similar in the past. I'll link it once i find. Basic idea is to create a script that calls zenity program and give it file as argument.

Comment: Here it is :  http://askubuntu.com/a/772163/295286

Comment: @Serg Sorry I spent 15 minutes writing my answer while you were searching for another. Let me know if it's better and I'll delete my answer.

Comment: Meh, the idea is basically the same, but your approach might be better - maybe they want to edit list later in libreoffice

Comment: If its just a plain text file you could use `conky` to have an eye-candy readonly todo list as part of your desktop. Editing would be a separate thing for sure.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your first step is to find out the name of your notepad / GUI editor / writer program as described in this Q&A: [How does one find out the command line corresponding to GUI app (eg, LibreOffice Writer)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80977/how-does-one-find-out-the-command-line-corresponding-to-gui-app-eg-libreoffice) In my case I use LibreOffice Write and the command is `libreoffice --writer`.

The next step is to select `Dash` which is the first option on the `Launcher`. In the search field type in `Startup` and select the icon **Startup Applications**. The following window pops up:

[image: Startup Applications]

Select the `Add` button. And this window appears:

[image]

Fill in your writer / program name and pass it the name of your to-do file. This is probably the hardest part to get right and often requires a little experimentation.

### Edit 1

Proving that experimentation is needed when using the above example tonight an error was displayed:

[image: ToDo does not exist]

Checking the actual file name ends in `.odt` edit the Startup Application profile and change the file name by adding the extension `.odt` and then voila on every boot you get:

[image: ToDo List]

Answer (score 3):

To display it using a shell script copy & paste this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# my to do list
cat filename
```

into a new text file & save it with a .sh extension, then add it to startup as explained above. If you want to display the contents of a longer file replace "cat" with "less".