# To-do app for Ubuntu?

Tags: 16.04, software-recommendation, productivity

Is there any good to-do app for Ubuntu?
Need some to plan my university life.
Best would be with a chance to pin it on desktop screen like sticky notes in Windows.

Comment: Did you check to see if `notes` is ready installed?  If your desktop is Unity, press the Super Key, then type in notes.  Any other version I believe is just in the menu under Accessories called notes.

Comment: Someone asked a similar question but wanted To-Do list to pop up automatically on boot. If you are interested the answer is here: [http://askubuntu.com/questions/826887/how-can-i-display-text-from-a-file-automatically-after-powering-up-my-computer/826898#826898]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Tasque. It is available in the Ubuntu Software Center or you can download it from [here](https://tasque.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu). It's good for local tasks. Tasque can store the list locally or with Remember the Milk's API and has an average rating.