# High DPi screen xrandr scaling on ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: gnome, 18.04, xorg, display-resolution, xrandr

I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS in dual boot with Windows 10 on my Thinkpad X1 Yoga 2nd gen which has a high dpi screen (2560x1440). Since the GUI settings do not permit fractional scaling (and 100% is too small while 200% is [too big](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01Ytu.png)) I followed the intructions in [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/HiDPI#Fractional_Scaling) page.

However, running the following command from terminal

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1.3x1.3 --panning 2560x1440
```

I get a pretty [bad result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/muMjD.png) where the desktop is resized and I get black borders. Moreover I can drag windows in the balck borders but they leave a trace beheind (picture [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9b4vz.png)).

I think it may be a conflict between xrandr and the Gnome desktop enviromment, but it's just a guess. Any suggestions on how to solve this bug?

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue too. Something that worked for me is to run the two parts of the command separately:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1.25x1.25
xrandr --output eDP-1 --panning 2560x1440
```

I then don't get the black borders. This didn't work in a start-up script, however -- I have to run this every time I log in.

After I suspend and resume, however, the black borders show up again. If anyone has any tips for getting around that, that'd be appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem for me.

Comment: I had to put `sleep 2` in between the two commands.

Answer (score 2):

This answers both the OP's question and the other answer's bonus question.

Create a script using:

```bash
sudo -H gedit /lib/systemd/system-sleep/scale
```

Copy these lines into `gedit`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# NAME: scale
# PATH: /lib/systemd/system-sleep
# DESC: Reset Ethernet card after suspend, not working automatically
# DATE: Dec 8, 2018


MYNAME=$0

set_scale() {
   xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 1.3x1.3
   xrandr --output eDP-1 --panning 2560x1440
}

/usr/bin/logger $MYNAME 'case=[' ${1}' ]'
case "${1}/${2}" in
   hibernate|suspend|pre*)
      ;;
   resume|thaw|post*)
      # sleep 2;
      set_scale;;
esac
```

Save the script and exit `gedit`.

Mark the script executable using:

```bash
chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/scale
```

The script will run every time you resume from suspend.

You can also have it run in your [startup applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826887/how-can-i-display-text-from-a-file-automatically-after-powering-up-my-computer/826898#826898) by adding an entry containing the command:

```bash
/lib/systemd/system-sleep/scale post suspend
```

Startup Applications are run **after** you sign on.