# Welcome file in every new user

Tags: 16.04

I need to make a welcome pdf file appears in all new (graphic desktop) users.
can someone give me a clue of where to start?

Regards.

Comment: What do you mean by "appears"? how are you adding users? check the `adduser` manual page for usage of the `SKEL` directory

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please edit your question and add new information. What do you mean by appear in all new users? Do you mean the PDF file will appear in the documents folder, or the desktop folder, where the user can open it? Do you mean the file will automatically open when the user logs in? If the file is to open automatically, should it open every time or just the first time the user logs in?

Comment: This question is similar but not an exact duplicate: [How can I display text from a file automatically after powering up my computer, in text editor or terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826887/how-can-i-display-text-from-a-file-automatically-after-powering-up-my-computer/826898#826898)

Answer (score 1):

Go to *Startup Applications*.

Click *Add*.

In command:

```
evince /path/to/your/pdf
```

*Add* and done.